# Proving that $x_{n+1} = ax_{n}(1-x_{n})$ converges when $1<a<3$.

Tags: convergence-divergence, recurrence-relations, recursion

I need some guidance for proving $x_{n+1} = ax_{n}(1-x_{n})$ converges when $1<a<3$.

What are some tips you guys could give me to help prove this point, without telling me how to do it? I'm half-way through Calculus I if that means anything to you guys.

Edit: $x_0 = .5$

Comment: @Winther That's not enough though. Boundness is required too.

Comment: @k99731 A has to be greater than 1, but less than 3.

Comment: My initital guess that the sequence will be monotone turns out to not be correct if $a>2$. The recursion here is known as the logistic map, you can read more about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_map).

Comment: @AnonBloke Oh I misunderstood the question.

Comment: The quadratic function $f(x)=ax-ax^2$ has two fixed points (intersection of a parabola with the line $y=x$), or one. Under some conditions a fixed point $\xi$ will be attractive, under some, repulsive. Decide, probably by looking at  $f'(\xi)$, which is which.